# In least squares estimation, why are the residuals constrained to lie within the space defined by the following equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, least-squares

I've been reading through the [Wikipedia article on degrees of freedom (statistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#Of_residuals). There is a section about residuals, in relation to least squares estimation. The article says:

Suppose you have some model $Y_i=a+bx_i + \epsilon_i \text{ for } i=1,...,n$.

Let $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ be least squares estimators of $a$ and $b$.

We can compute the residuals as follows: $\hat e_i=y_i-(\hat a + \hat b x_i)$.

The article then says that these residuals are constrained to lie within the space defined by:

$\hat e_1 + \dots + \hat e_n=0$ and $x_1 \hat e_1 + \dots + x_n \hat e_n=0$.

Hence, they say there are $n-2$ degrees of freedom for error.

So, my first question is, where have these two constraints come from?

I guess the first one comes from the fact that the mean of the residuals is supposed to be $0$. The second one, I am not sure about.

I suppose when they say there are $n-2$ degrees of freedom for error, it means the residuals are constrained to lie within an ($n-2$)-dimensional subspace? Hence, my second question is, why do these constraints mean that the residuals are constrained to an ($n-2$)-dimensional subspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you form a design matrix $Z$ (with $n$ rows and $p$ columns), the column space of $Z$ spans some p-dimensional hyperplane. The residual vector -- formed from the difference between the response vector and its least squares projection onto the column space of $Z$ -- has to be perpendicular to the column space of $Z$. So the residual vector is constrained to lie within the left nullspace of $Z$. The dimension of the left nullspace of $Z$ is $n-p$, hence the residual vector has $n-p$ degrees of freedom.

In the example from the question, $p=2$, hence there are $n-2$ degrees of freedom for error. Furthermore, as stated, a residual vector is perpendicular to the column space. In other words, the residual vector is perpendicular to each column of $Z$. Hence, when you compute $\hat e_i ^T (\text{column of Z})$, this must equal zero. Each of these dot products gives each constraint. The first column of $Z$ is all $1$s, hence the sum of residuals is $0$. Each column after that will have actual data in it, hence each residual is multiplied by a covariant.

Answer (score 1):

You find $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ by looking for minima of the function (in $a$ and $b$):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-a-bx_i)^2$$

so taking partial derivatives in $a$ and $b$ and making them equal to $0$ yields:

$$0=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-a-bx_i)^2\right]_{a=\hat{a},b=\hat{b}}=-2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{a}-\hat{b}x_i)=-2\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{e_i}$$

$$0=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-a-bx_i)^2\right]_{a=\hat{a},b=\hat{b}}=-2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{a}-\hat{b}x_i)x_i=-2\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{e_i}x_i$$

which gives you the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

So, for a given choice of a and b, the sum of the square of the error is by definition $$S=\sum_i(y_i-a-bx_i)^2.$$  So $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}=-2\sum(y_i-a-bx_i)$$ and $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}=-2\sum x_i(y_i-a-bx_i)$$.

$\hat a$ and $\hat b$ are by definition those values of a and b that set these partial derivatives to zero (minimising S).

So $$\sum(y_i-\hat a- \hat bx_i) = 0$$ and $$\sum x_i(y_i-\hat a- \hat bx_i) = 0,$$ which are respectively equivalent to $$ \sum \hat e_i = 0$$ and $$ \sum \hat e_i x_i = 0,$$ the two constraints in the Wikipedia article.

To answer your second question, imagine the case where n=3. The coordinates $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ can take any value in 3-dimensional space.

If we impose just the first condition, $e_1+e_2+e_3=0$, that defines a (2-dimensional) plane.  If we impose just the second condition (for given fixed $x_i$) $x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 + x_3 e_3 = 0$ that defines a plane in $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$-space too (a different one for most choices of $x_i$).

Imposing both conditions, we take the intersection of two planes, which is a 1-dimensional line.  So the set of possible $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ has been constrained to $(n-2)$ dimensions.  The same works for higher n, but less easy to visualise.